How to connect RabbitMQ "stream" in Apache Flink?
Is there a way to connect RabbitMQ "stream" instead of a queue in Apache Flink?
Thank you!
I'm able to get a RabbitMQ queue as a source working in Apache Flink but how to get a RabbitMQ stream working in Flink?
[Update]
I resolved this problem by implementing a RichParallelSourceFunction with run() method

instantiating RabbitMQ environment connecting to RabbitMQ stream
sourceContext collecting all the messages received from RabbitMQ

`
 public class RabbitMqSource2 extends RichParallelSourceFunction<String> {
        private volatile boolean running = true;
        private Environment environment;
        private final String streamName = "superStreamName";
        private final String consumerName = "Consumer1";
    
        @Override
        public void run(SourceContext<String> sourceContext) throws Exception {
                if (Objects.isNull(environment)) {
                    environment = Environment.builder().uris(Arrays.asList(
                                    "rabbitmq-stream://usrname:pwd1@Server1:5522/%2f",
                                    "rabbitmq-stream://usrname:pwd1@Server2:5522/%2f",
                                    "rabbitmq-stream://usrname:pwd1@Server3:5522/%2f")
                            )
                            .host("Server3")
                            .port(5522)
                            .username("usrname")
                            .password("pwd1")
                            .virtualHost("/")
                            .build();
                }
                environment.consumerBuilder()
                        .superStream(streamName)
                        .name(consumerName)
                        .singleActiveConsumer()
                        .messageHandler((context, message) -> {

                            if(message != null && message.getProperties() != null && message.getProperties().getMessageIdAsString() != null) {
                                String msg = new String(message.getBodyAsBinary());

                                sourceContext.collect(msg);
                            }
                        })
                        .build();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            environment.close();
        }
    }

`


Flink supports an official RabbitMQ Connector that should support any implementation you'd need to either use RabbitMQ as a source or a sink.
If you already have a source defined that is reading from RabbitMQ as a queue, you could likely override this to support your desired behavior by creating your own extension of the RMQSource class that would allow you more fine-grained control and configuration of the behavior of the source.
Per the source you should be able to override the RMQSource.setupQueue() function in your own implementation to avoid explicitly using a queue:
protected void setupQueue() throws IOException {
    Util.declareQueueDefaults(channel, queueName);
}

This blog post while a bit dated provides an example implementation of what something like that might look like:
public class RabbitmqStreamProcessor extends RMQSource{

    // This is mainly because we have to bind our queue to an exchange. 
    // If you are using a queue directly, you may skip it.
    @Override
    protected void setupQueue() throws IOException {
        AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk result = channel.queueDeclare("simple_dev", true, false, false, null);
        channel.queueBind(result.getQueue(), "simple_exchange", "*");
    }
}



I did try this option and also a variant based on documentation from RabbitMQ. None of it helps. Get the error Cannot create RMQ connection with xyz at abc
@Override
protected void setupQueue() throws IOException {
    AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk result = channel.queueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, Collections.singletonMap("x-queue-type", "stream"));
    channel.queueBind(result.getQueue(), exchangeName, "*");
}


Also in the page, https://shekharsingh.com/blog/2016/11/12/apache-flink-rabbimq-streams-processor.html he's binding a queue to an exchange and not a rabbitmq stream.
